Microsoft Excel pivot table
I want same data type to be categorized in one line, for e.g PO should be in same line giving me a total count of 43, instead it differentiates the PO into 2, pls how can i fix this



Check your source data, could be there are trailing or leading spaces.

gone through this nothing seems off with spaces

Without sample data one cannot say what you have but the first assumption would be of any white space or unwanted non printable characters, can you post your data.

i've added a screenshot of the source data.

Looks like there are leading spaces, also asked for some data, with screenshots one cannot determine whether there are non printable characters or not.

And I can see not just for PO but there are other file types where the pivot is showing twice with different counts. Do a thorough check of your data.

Apply in your source data =TRIM() to remove all trailing and leading spaces and then ensure that you refresh the data for your pivot table.

thanks, the TRIM function did the Job

@nnaemeka_DS which means you source data had spaces. Note that TRIM() removes leading or trailing spaces. and you said there are no spaces. strange.

i manually inputed the source data myself and i was quite sure there wasnt any leading space, could have been trailing spaces. i also notice that my pivot table represented empty rows and counted them, i really dont want this empty rows shown

@nnaemeka_DS you need to filter those empty rows out.
